# How do you render limited content in a Scroll View?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Basically, I'm creating a transaction history feed & if the user has a ridiculous amount of transactions it'll lag because my app is trying to render the entire contents of the scroll view

On Twitter I see that they'll render say ~50 tweets then when you get to the bottom and pull it'll show an ActivityIndicator then render an additional 50 tweets

How do you get this type of behavior in React Native?

Comment: Basically, you have to use ```onEndReached```with ```onEndReachedThreshold``` when the scroll get closes to the bottom of the screen the callback is called so you have to handle all logic in the callback to get more result from api.
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#onendreached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a fairly simple solution, called **lazy loading.**

First of all you'll need to make sure the API endpoint used for getting those transactions supports **pagination.**

The way Twitter app works is:

1. First time the component is rendered the **first page** is fetched
2. Each time the user hits the bottom of the list (and the loading indicator is displayed) the **next page** (from the API endpoint mentioned above) is fetched and rendered.

In **React Native** you can achieve this by using the `<Flatlist />` component. It has a prop called [onEndReached](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#onendreached) which will allow you to build this behavior. You can also use [onEndReachedThreshold](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#onendreachedthreshold) to controll when the next page fetch is happening. Both props are docummented very well.

It's up to you to decide how many transactions are on each *page*,  but you should be safe with 50.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour can be achieved easily using flatlist. There is a prop called on **onEndReached** which gets called when the user reached the end of the list. You can basically hit the api in this callback to get more result and append that data in the list and this will automatically refresh your list with new data.

```
<FlatList
data={data} //coming from state or redux
onEndReached={() => this.getMoreData()}
/>

const getMoreData=()=>{
 //in this function hit the api and append the data to the existing list
}
```